# A Map/Reduce solution using Spark and Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a problem of finding the most rated tags for books, My data looks like this

**Books**

```
+---+--------------------+-----------+
| id|                tags|      title|
+---+--------------------+-----------+
|  1| PHP, JAVA, XML, SQL| First Book|
|  2|     PHP, Javascript|Second Book|
|  3|PHP, Javascript, ...| Third Book|
|  4|PHP, RUBY, YAML, SQL|Fourth Book|
+---+--------------------+-----------+
```

**Ratings**

```
+-------+------+----+
|book_id|rating|user|
+-------+------+----+
|      1|     4|  15|
|      3|     2|  15|
|      1|     5|  17|
|      2|     3|  21|
+-------+------+----+
```

The solution I came up with makes use of SparkSQL, because I am more familiar with SQL

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Books").getOrCreate()
val tags = books.withColumn("tags_splitted", split($"tags", ",")).withColumn("tag_exploded", explode($"tags_splitted")).select("id", "tag_exploded")
tags.createOrReplaceTempView("tags")
ratings.createOrReplaceTempView("ratings")
val result = spark.sql("SELECT tag_exploded, count(*) FROM tags, ratings WHERE tags.id = ratings.book_id GROUP BY tag_exploded ORDER BY count(*) DESC")
```

While that gives me the result I am after, I am wondering if there is a better way of solving this using map/reduce on Spark. This doesn't look like it takes advantage of parallel/distributed processing to me

Comment: Spark doesn't use MapReduce.

Comment: The functions documented [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/programming-guide.html#transformations) like map(), reduceByKey() etc suggests that it does?

Comment: But that is not equivalent to what you see in hadoop MapReduce. There are no mappers, reducers etc. The execution is different from Hadoop Map Reduce.

Comment: To be sure, Scala/Spark support the logical map-reduce paradigm, but as @philantrovert states, they're fundamentally different in terms of execution.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. MapReduce algorithm is implemented differently by Hadoop Mapreduce and Spark. Thanks for the explanation @erip

Comment: So if I wanted to optimize the above to be executed in a Spark cluster, would I implement the code differently or will Spark handle that as it is?